# using jquery to traverse dom for scraping data

Tags: jquery, dom, web-scraping, jquery-traversing

I am working with the node phantom simple  https://github.com/baudehlo/node-phantom-simple.  It has made scraping the dom very simple.  I am allowed to use jquery and I am getting into the data-table library.

Here is the code that I started with

```
 var nameArray = [];

        $("tbody[role='alert'] tr").each(function(data){
              var json = {};
              json.name= $(this).children(':first-child').text();
              json.size= $(this).children(':nth-child(2)').text();
              json.caffeine= $(this).children(':nth-child(3)').text();
              json.mgFloz=$(this).children(':last-child').text();
            nameArray.push(json);
        });

        // return tableData;
            return nameArray;
```

I am returning all of the data from the website that I have scraped.  Inside of each table row is the format

```
<td><a href="">name of drink</a></td>
<td>info</td>
<td>info</td>
<td> info</td>
```

I am seeking to access the drink href.  So i tried to target the html

```
json.url=$(this).children(':first-child').html();
```

I my response is

```
{ url: '<a href="/caffeine-content/zombie-blood-energy-potion">Zombie Blood Energy Potion</a>' }
```

This is close.  All that I want is the href and I will be done.  I tried targeting with attr() but I kept getting null back.

Is there a step I am missing or a work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, but you need to traverse the DOM one more layer down. Use [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
json.url = $(this).children(':first-child').find('a').attr('href');
```

For the `name` property, you can use a similar approach:

```
json.name = $(this).children(':first-child').find('a').text();
```

Comment: @stevek No problem. Please note that the line you showed us in the example that you are using for the `url` property is exactly the same line you are using for the `name` property above that. This means that your `name` value is going to be the full HTML code for the `a` inside the first `td`. You need to use my example in order to get the "name of drink" part.

Comment: @stevek Please do not forget to mark this as the answer if it answered your question. Thanks!